# in code better time format strategy. milliseconds or concat time string?

Tags: date-time, geolocation

Which of these should I choose for time formatting?
    1. Wednesday, June 3, 2020 11:34:10 PM GMT-04:00
    2. 1591241594000

what answer should have I provided? I was guessing 2. but is there a better answer?

Any particular library that helps achieve the conversion in goLang?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

7. Assuming that this value is in milliseconds since ephoch:
   GMT: Tuesday, November 28, 2017 8:00:12.078 AM

The + is time zone offset